# CORS Missing Allow Oirign with angular, spring webflux and spring oauth2 client

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-webflux, cross-origin-resource-policy

I want to create a simple webapp based on Angular. That is able to retrieve data from the with oauth secured battlenet resource server.

My planned structure is like.

- Angular
- Spring boot as oauth2 client using spring webflux
- Battlenet authentication + resource server

I was able to setup my spring boot app, that I'm able to retrieve data by direct endpoint calls via browser.

If I try to do the same via angular app, I'm getting cross origin errors while oauth authentication.

**[Browser info from inspect -> network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9nJL.png)**

**My configuration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain configure(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        return http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
                    .authorizeExchange(auth -> auth.anyExchange().authenticated())
                    .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
                    .build();
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(List.of("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setMaxAge(3600L);
        configuration.applyPermitDefaultValues();

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepo,
                               ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepo) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction filter =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                        clientRegistrationRepo,
                        authorizedClientRepo);
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl("https://eu.api.blizzard.com")
                .filter(filter)
                .build();
    }

}
```

**My rest controller**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/user")
    public Mono<String> getUserName(@AuthenticationPrincipal Mono<OAuth2User> oauth2User) {
        return oauth2User
                .mapNotNull(OAuth2User::getName)
                .map(name -> String.format("Hi, %s", name));
    }

}
```

**My Angular App Demo call**

```
  sendRequest() {
    const headers= new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');

    const requestOptions = { headers: headers };

    this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/user')
              .subscribe(response => this.apiResponse = response);
  }
```

Please, help me to solve this cors issue.

Answer (score -1):

Your CORS error is on a request to battle.net. It can't be fixed with the configuration of your Angular or Spring applications.

Instead of following redirects to battle.net within your app:

- temporarily "quit" your Angular app by setting the `window.location.href` to the battle.net authorization endpoint. That way origin will be battle.net (and not your Angular app)
- be sure to use a redirect_uri pointing to your Spring app authorization-code endpoint (`http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/your-registration-id`)
- in Spring OAuth2 client, configure a success URL to return to your Angular app (`http://localhost:4200/`, unless your Spring client is a `spring-cloud-gateway` also proxying your Angular app with route like `http://localhost:8080/ui`)

I have written [a tutorial](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff) with an Angular app querying a Spring reactive OAuth2 client (a `spring-cloud-gateway` instance). You can see how login is initiated in the Angular app [there](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/blob/b4cf7402a38f0d2f80a81fcd1efa0c1c5312d407/samples/tutorials/bff/angular/projects/bff-ui/src/app/user.service.ts#L40).

Comment: I will check your tutorial but I already got an question regarding your first point. Wouldn't it be also possible to redirect my angular app to my backend fulfill the oauth authentication and return to my angular app?

Comment: Is `http://127.0.0.1:8080` an allowed origin on battle.net? If you read my tutorial, note that the Authorization request is not hard-coded in Angular app: it is provided by the Spring app on an endpoint exposing options for login (you could have one per client registration with authorization_code in your application properties)